# Local javascript stopped working after including materialize collapsable navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

So, the JavaScript for my project stopped working after including the materialize JavaScript code needed to make my nav bar turn into a hamburger on mobile devices. I've tried placing my file at the bottom of the html, before the navbar script, and after it. Each time is the same, the hamburger and materialize js works but my js file that I'm using for password validation does not.. Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Register Page</title>

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Our own style sheet -->        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <!-- For icons -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
          var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
        });
    </script>


</head>
<body>

  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#!" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <ul class="sidenav" id="mobile-demo">
    <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="register.html">Register</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
    <div class="contact-box">
        <div class="row">
            <form class="col s12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
                        <input id="icon_prefix" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="icon_prefix">Full Name</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">email</i>
                        <input id="icon_prefix" type="email" class="validate">
                        <label for="icon_prefix">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <i class="material-icons prefix">password</i>
                        <input id="psw" type="password" name="psw" class="validate" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" required>
                        <label for="icon_prefix">Password</label>
                    </div>
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Submit
                            <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
ss3
<div id="message">
  <h5>Password must contain the following:</h5>
        <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
        <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
        <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
        <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the validation.js file:

```
 // Script for validating password. This code was authored by w3schools at the url: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_password_validation.asp

var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var length = document.getElementById("length");

// When the user clicks on the password field, show the message box
myInput.onfocus = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks outside of the password field, hide the message box
myInput.onblur = function() {
  document.getElementById("message").style.display = "none";
}

// When the user starts to type something inside the password field
myInput.onkeyup = function() {
  // Validate lowercase letters
  var lowerCaseLetters = /[a-z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(lowerCaseLetters)) {
    letter.classList.remove("invalid");
    letter.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    letter.classList.remove("valid");
    letter.classList.add("invalid");
}

  // Validate capital letters
  var upperCaseLetters = /[A-Z]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(upperCaseLetters)) {
    capital.classList.remove("invalid");
    capital.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    capital.classList.remove("valid");
    capital.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate numbers
  var numbers = /[0-9]/g;
  if(myInput.value.match(numbers)) {
    number.classList.remove("invalid");
    number.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    number.classList.remove("valid");
    number.classList.add("invalid");
  }

  // Validate length
  if(myInput.value.length >= 8) {
    length.classList.remove("invalid");
    length.classList.add("valid");
  } else {
    length.classList.remove("valid");
    length.classList.add("invalid");
  }
}
```

Am I placing my JavaScript file in the wrong area? I've tried placing it in the body with the same results too. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: do you see any errors in the browser console?

Comment: Yes, I got the following: Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content. 
Uncaught TypeError: myInput is null
    <anonymous> http://localhost/frontendcc/validation.js:10

Comment: `myInput is null` - that's the issue

Comment: Hmm, yes but why is it null and how would I fix it? It works fine w/o the js required for the mobile navbar.

Comment: indeed, why is it null - I can't see the code that causes the error, but you can

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to post the script code. It's there now, if you could take a look and give me some ideas i'd be grateful :D

Comment: running `var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");` in `<HEAD>` will never work, since the element hasn't loaded yet - that code needs to run after the element is loaded

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234885/discussion-between-jstone-and-bravo).

Answer (score 0):

Please put your JS file at the end in the `<body>` tag. like this,

```
<body>
...
...
<div id="message">
  <h5>Password must contain the following:</h5>
        <p id="letter" class="invalid">A <b>lowercase</b> letter</p>
        <p id="capital" class="invalid">A <b>capital (uppercase)</b> letter</p>
        <p id="number" class="invalid">A <b>number</b></p>
        <p id="length" class="invalid">Minimum <b>8 characters</b></p>
</div>
...
...
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
      var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems);
    });
</script>

<!-- my own JavaScript file -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="validation.js"></script>
</body>
```

And also please use a listener in your file to know that the entire document is first loaded so that your code will get the DOM which it is looking for.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
   // Script for validating password. This code was authored by w3schools at the url: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_password_validation.asp

   var myInput = document.getElementById("psw");
   var letter = document.getElementById("letter");
   var capital = document.getElementById("capital");
   ...
   ...
});
```

You can also use `DOMContentLoaded` if you are not concerned about the stylesheet loading.

Comment: I did everything you said and it still isn't working for me :( thanks though

Comment: Can you give the error log from the console?

Comment: Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.